# How to add more space between columns of knitr::kable() in RStudio notebooks?

Tags: r, rstudio, kable, rnotebook

I want to use function `knitr::kable()` in an RStudio notebook.
If column names are short, the spaces between columns are small and it makes information hard to understand (see figure below). It seems that `padding` does not work in this situation. Is there a way to make spaces between the columns (indicated by yellow arrows) larger in RStudio notebooks?

```r
library(magrittr)
iris %>% 
  setNames(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")) %>%
  head() %>%
  knitr::kable(padding = 20)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You could use `kableExtra` for nicer styling in general, including wider column spacing by default.

```
library(magrittr)
library(kableExtra)

iris %>% 
  setNames(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")) %>%
  head() %>%
  knitr::kable() %>% 
  kable_styling()
```